# Account Link Error when Using Device Access Console

Tags: nest-device-access

I have a Nest Hub Max device and trying to control via API.  I have a GCP account with associated OAUTH Client ID and a project ID from the Device Access Console.

I am attempting to link the GCP OAUTH ID and the Device Access Console project but reach screen with message:

"No access to partner - Information could not be retrieved. Please contact NestHubMax to verify that your account has been properly set up. You may need to add the developer email address as a home member in the Google Home app settings."

Answer (score 0):

Have you added your email address to the test users list in the GCP OAuth Consent Screen settings?